# How is youtube comments feature implemented?

Tags: ajax, youtube, comments

How is youtube comments feature implemented?
I see that they use AJAX but they don't do AJAX calls every second or two.Ajax call is made when there is a new comment on the video.
On my page I call a page every 5 seconds with AJAX.
So how are they doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personnally when i have a look at Firebug to see Ajax Request, i have one who's called every 2-3 seconds with parameters :

```
asv    3
ctp    2
docid      DbYtqAWDF2U
el     detailpage
et     20.087
fmt    34
ns     yt
plid       AASgAO8pqC5GDlo9
st     20.087
vid    VcyzE1TkaJrg4jlA8I_rWIK6z2TaXNB3R
yttk       1
```

docid is just the id of the video, $_GET['v'] var too.

Comment: "Gunther-ding ding dong", seriously?

Comment: Haha, I didn't know if anyone would notice.

Answer (score 0):

It uses Ajax and if you see the content of the ajax call it contains poll_delay value which is something like 60,000 which means when it has to poll the live comments again.60 seconds in this case.